# Do RESTful web services loose their advantage in a closed network or LAN?

Tags: web-services, rest, lan

The advantage of REST in utilizing the HTTP standards when implementing web services makes sense when deploying such a service on the web, having CDNs along the way etc. In a closed environment however, e.g. within a university or a bank's LAN do we gain any benefits of HTTP by using REST?

Answer (score 1):

The benefit is simply the fact that you build a layer of abstraction between the database and clients querying it therefore limiting what can be done, as well as standardize the data structures so your client code can depend on it staying the same.